# C# Unity; Sending a variable to a method as a pointer/reference or similar instead of whatever value the variable has

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pointers, reference

I am trying to make a script that will display the direction of a force with an arrow. The arrow is a GameObject that is initialized at startup. Upon initialization the `public static GameObject ForceArrowBase` is set to the object that already exists. This object is then instantiated when calling `CreateNewForceArrow`.

The `forceVector` in the ForceArrow class should *not* be a value, but rather some sort of reference/pointer or something in that nature. So when `forceArrow.forceVector = forceVector` is being called in the `CreateNewForceArrow` method, it shouldn't set the value to be whatever the value is at that point in time. Rather, it should set it to refer to the part of the memory that holds the variable data of the caller.

So when `WindForce`'s `Wind.Data.Speed` changes, the `forceVector` in the `ForceArrow` refers to the data point `Wind.Data.Speed`.

In a way, it would be: `void ForceVector { get => Wind.Data.Speed; }`. But of course, if the `CreateNewForceArrow` method was called by `ForceCreatingScript2`, then it should be: `void ForceVector { get => instancedForceCreatingScript2.forceOutput; }`

So, is there anyway to parse the variable in as a pointer-type-thingy rather than the value of the variable?

```cs
public class ForceArrow : MonoBehaviour {
    public static GameObject ForceArrowBase;
    private static bool _initialized = false;

    public GameObject refObject;
    public Vector3 forceVector;
    public float force;

    public void FixedUpdate() {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forceVector);
    }

    public static void CreateNewForceArrow(string name, ref Vector3 forceVectorReference, GameObject forceObject) {
        var forceArrowObject = Instantiate<GameObject>(ForceArrowBase);
        var forceArrow = forceArrowObject.GetComponent<ForceArrow>();

        forceArrowObject.transform.position = forceObject.transform.position;
        forceArrowObject.gameObject.name = name + "_forceArrow";

        forceArrow.forceVector = forceVectorReference;
        forceArrow.refObject = forceObject;
    }
}
public class ForceCreatingScript1 : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 forceVector;
    void Start() {
        ForceArrow.CreateNewForceArrow(name, ref forceVector, gameObject);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        forceVector *= 1.2f;
    }
}
public class ForceCreatingScript2 : MonoBehaviour {
    public Vector3 forceOutput;
    void Start() {
        ForceArrow.CreateNewForceArrow(name, ref forceOutput, gameObject);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        forceOutput *= 1.6f;
    }
}
public class WindForce : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        ForceArrow.CreateNewForceArrow(name, ref Wind.Data.SpeedVector, gameObject);
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        Wind.Data.Speed = Mathf.Clamp(Wind.Data.Speed + Wind.WindRandom(), 15, Wind.MaximumWindSpeed);
        Wind.Data.SpeedVector = BISH_MathHelper.DegreeToVector3(Wind.Data.DegAngle);
        Wind.Data.RadAngle = (Wind.Data.RadAngle + Wind.WindRandom() / 80f) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you looked up passing by reference?

Comment: @BugFinder I am doing it atm, but as I understand it, it only opens up the possibility to change the parsed variable within the method. But doing the forceArrow.forceVector = forceVector still just set the variables value, it doesn't keep the reference.